# WSL- Ubuntu install - Certificate authority is invalid or incorrect - System path cannot be specified

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have uninstalled WSL which had Ubuntu 20.04.6 installed. Once uninstalled, I have enabled the feature and tried to reinstall Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store.  When starting Ubuntu, I'm getting the error `System path cannot be found`.  Also, when I try to install WSL via PowerShell, I'm getting `Certificate authority is invalid or incorrect`.

Kindly help.